# Printing an average in python, using a list

Tags: python, list, append, average, calculator

This code needs to calculate an average to retrieve an integer between 0-100. Any suggestions would be great.

- Prompt the user for the number of points they expect to receive
  for engagement at the end of class. This number should not be
  adjusted by the program (engagement is a total of 302).
- Calculate the final based on an average of the quiz scores to
  date.
- Prompt the user for the various scores. -1 = no more scores, 0 -
  zero for that assignment. Keep looping for the grade until the user
  enters a -1.

Here is my code, I definitely do not understand lists very well. Probably clearly.

```
list1 = []
g=1
totalnum = 0
total=0
tot = int(input("Total Points? :"))
list1.append(tot)
eng = int(input("How many points do you expect to get in engangement, out of 302?: "))
list1.append(eng)

while g !=0:
    num = int(input("Please enter a grade"))
    if num == -1:
        break
    totalnum+=1
    total= total+num
    list1.append(num)

average= tot/eng+num
counter=0
while counter<totalnum:
    print(list1[counter])
    counter+=1

print("your average is",average)
```

Comment: the line 'average= tot/eng+num' looks suspect.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use built ins you can just use `sum(your_list) / len(your_list)` for the average.

If `len(your_list)` is zero, you will get a `ZeroDivisionError`, because you just broke math.

Comment: remember to check for `len(your_list) >0`!

Comment: Pesky `ZeroDivisionError` exceptions :[

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me that this is what you're trying to accomplish, but if you just want an average of all the values in the list, you can just do:

```
average = sum(list)/len(list)
```

This would return an integer, if you don't want it rounded you could do:

```
average = sum(list)/float(len(list))
```

As an aside, you have this:

```
counter=0
while counter<totalnum:
    print(list1[counter])
    counter+=1
```

Which could be made simpler, like:

```
for e in list1:
    print e
```

Python will do the counting for you. :)

Comment: remember to check for len(list) >0!

Comment: In general that's a great point, but in this case the list is populated by the user inputs, so it seems like we'd never get to this step with an empty list.

Comment: this still has not given me an average. What the program is supposed to do, is basically calculate a students class grade, with the user inputing the total amount points possible, and then the user adding in point's given as a grade. so if someone got a 9/10 on a test, the user would input the number 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = []
g=1
totalnum = 0
total=0

tot = int(input("Total Points? :"))
eng = int(input("How many points do you expect to get in engangement, out of 302?: "))
list1.append(eng)

while g !=0:
    num = int(input("Please enter a grade"))
    if num == -1:
        break
    else:
        list1.append(num)   
        totalnum+=1
        total= (num+eng)/tot
print(len(list1))  
average = (sum(list1)/tot)*100
counter=0
for e in list1:
    print (e)

print("your average is",average)
```

This is more what I was looking for. Thanks to @Tommy, @SQLnoob, and @Slayer for the tips that I have implemented into the code.